# Define custom roles

Tags: asp.net, roles

I am developing a content management Site and define custom roles.

Can anyone tell me the way how to get defined custom roles for my members and subsequent Menus for these roles and how to manage all these?

Please note: We are not using Asp.net Membership Provider, we have to apply our custom roles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on the Membership and Roles providers in ASP.NET.

http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/427.aspx

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response. Unfortunately, we are not using Asp.net Membership, we have to apply custom membership. I have edited my question accordingly.